# Where to hide password to sql server while deploying django app into Azure from github?

Tags: django, azure, github

I'm trying to deploy my app on Azure, but I don't know where may I hide a password to SQL server.
I usually hide it with decouple module or in environment, but while deploying azure doesn't have access to those.

And without this password I get error while running oryx build:

```
raise UndefinedValueError('{} not found. Declare it as envvar or define a default value.'.format(option))
decouple.UndefinedValueError: PASSWORD not found. Declare it as envvar or define a default value.
```

Does anyone has an idea how to do so?

Answer (score 0):

If you're deploying with a pipeline, like Azure pipelines or github actions, there should be a secrets management service that you can use to give your pipeline access to your SQL server password securely (and it can then set things in the deployment as you need)

If you're using Azure pipelines, have a look at the key vault (https://azuredevopslabs.com/labs/vstsextend/azurekeyvault/)

and if you're using github actions, have a look at github secrets (https://docs.github.com/en/actions/configuring-and-managing-workflows/creating-and-storing-encrypted-secrets)